# SSRS datepart #error in report

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to set a simple expression in SSRS in my report using the **datepart** function:

```
=datepart("dw",Fields!period_dt.Value)
```

When I preview the report, the values come up as #error.

Am I missing something completely obvious here?

The **Fields!period_dt.Value** field contains dates in this format 12/31/2013 12:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your expression:

```
=datepart("dw",Fields!period_dt.Value)
```

`dw` is not a valid datepart.

Assuming you want the day of the week, use:

```
=datepart("w",Fields!period_dt.Value)
```

or

```
=datepart(DateInterval.Weekday,Fields!period_dt.Value)
```

Which both return `3` for `12/31/2013 12:00:00`.

See [DatePart Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20ee97hz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more details on this.

Comment: Boy do i feel stupid now...Thank you so much! it worked!

Comment: You're welcome! Considering T-SQL would be fine with `dw` it wasn't an unreasonable assumption...